# View results tree sampler in jenkins

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter

Is it possible to see "view results tree " sampler of jmeter in jenkins. I want to see all my request and response data of jmeter in jenkins. i am not able to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JMeter does not store the response data when it is being run in non-GUI mode, however you can override this by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

But be aware that:

1. It changes results output format to XML so if you have any post processors which explicitly rely on CSV default format (i.e. [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)) - they might fail
2. Storing request and response data causes massive RAM and Disk IO overheads so JMeter will consume way more memory hence throughput might be lower. It is recommended to use the above settings only for debugging or investigation when something definitely goes wrong and revert them back to defaults once you figure out and eliminate the root cause.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on using JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them

Comment: i have edited user.properties file  but In jenkins i am not able to see the changes. i.e my request and response data of jmeter in jenkins

Comment: I don't think you will be able to see it in directly in jenkins (at least I'm not aware of such plugins), you will need to open .jtl results file using JMeter GUI

Comment: can we get  any file in workspace. i got a file meter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml file

Comment: C:\software\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml, jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t C:\software\jmeterjenkins.jmx -l Test.jtl